# Whitney-like embedding theorem for posets?

Tags: order-theory, posets, embeddings

The Whitney embedding theorem says that any finite-dimensional smooth manifold can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. Is anything like this true for posets?

I'm looking for conditions on a poset $P$, under which there exists an embedding of $P$ into a cube $L^n$ for some linear order $L$. I'm interested in both the case that the dimension of the cube is finite and that in which it's necessarily infinite.

Of course, embeddability into a cube is itself a "condition" that's tautologically sufficient. So I'm not just looking for any condition, but for a "local condition", just like the structure of being a finite-dimensional smooth manifold is a local structure. I'm not sure exactly what locality should mean here for posets, but hopefully the community will know it when it sees it.

For example, taking $L=\mathbb{R}$, I'm asking:

> Under what (in some sense "local") conditions on a partially-ordered set $P$ does there exist an injective, monotone map $P\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for some possibly infinite $n$?

Counter-examples (i.e. proofs that certain conditions that are too weak) are of course also welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're considering the same problem that I did, but it seems to me the same (except that I looked at the discrete variant):
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168099/monotone-embedding-of-complete-binary-tree-in-hypercube

Comment: And also a paper showing that determining the smallest $n$ is hard:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08226

Comment: I don't understand the question. It is a classical (and trivial) fact that every partially ordered set $(P,\le)$ is isomorphic to a collection of sets ordered by inclusion, namely, $x\mapsto\{y\in P;y\le x\}$ embeds $P$ in the power set $\mathcal P(P),$ which is isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^P.$ What am I missing?

Comment: For discrete posets and without special conditions on $L$, this is straight forward, as pointed out by bof. If $L = \mathbb{R}$, your poset has a topology and you want the embedding into $L^n$ to be continuous, this problem is known as "presenting a partial order by isotone functions". A real function is isotone when it preserves the order. When the topology on $P$ is sufficiently nice, you can just take $P \to L^{C_{iso}(P)}$ where the isotone functions give the components of the embedding. References can be found, for instance, in https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5123

Comment: Thanks Bof. I think you did understand the question, you just didn't understand why I would ask something you found trivial. I hadn't heard of, nor noticed the embedding you mention. You're welcome to add it as an answer if you like, and I'll accept it.

And thanks Igor for the other link, which was actually quite useful.

Comment: You will probably find interesting the notion of [dimension of an ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension) - take a look at the "alternative definition". This is an active area of research, see e.g. the work of [Tom Trotter](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~trotter/).